# Where to store minor user data types when implementing DI/IoC

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection

There's a same question I keep asking myself each time a new Dependency Injection based solution is being started. I usually have a dedicated assembly for interfaces - this one is  referenced by each and every other solution modules. Should I need to use some small user data types, I use to store those in interfaces assembly also. This seems to be the most logical thing, however it always makes the inerface assembly project look like a trashbox.

And the question is - what's the best place for `SearchParams`, `SimpleTask` and `ComplexTask` to be kept in? Please refer to the example below.

That's how I use to do:
**Common.Interfaces**

```
interface IScheduler
{
    Boolean ScheduleTask(ITask task);
    ITask FindTask(SearchParameters search);
}

interface ITask { ... }

class SearchParameters { ... }
```

**Common.Scheduler**

```
class Scheduler : IScheduler { ... }

class SimpleTask : ITask { ... }

class ComplexTask : ITask { ... }
```

The problem with `SimpleTask` and `ComplexTask` here is it requires me to reference Common.Scheduler wherever I'm calling IScheduler.ScheduleTask(...). And the problem with `SearchParameters` is it wastes interface assmebly. Imagine there are hundreds of small types stored under the same assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to reference `Common.Scheduler` when you call `IScheduler.ScheduleTask`? This method correctly uses the interface, so calling this method doesn't require you to reference  `Common.Scheduler`.
You only need to reference that assembly if you are working with one of the concrete types `SimpleTask` or `ComplexTask`. In that case, it is correct that you need to reference that assembly.

Comment: Well, I need to create an instance of SimpleTask/ComplexTask (ITask implementors) to pass as a parameter.

Comment: Shouldn't this creation be in only a few places, so you use the interface where ever possible?

Comment: IMHO this is a completely different scenario. SearchParams wouldn't have an interface, because it is merely a DTO without any logic in it.

Comment: This particular case was never a show stopper. I mean I do use to create DI cores dealing with assumptions, restrictions and agreements like this one above. I'm just trying to figure out the best practice, 'cause it feels really weird to reference a scheduler engine assembly just to get use of couple descriptor-types which ComplexTask and SimpleTask are. However, the only way I see to omit the reference - move ComplexTask and SimpleTask to Common.Interfaces and create a trashbox of it.

Comment: Around DTO - that's the only criteria I currently use to determine, whether I want to expand a trashbox with one more type or produce another one reference requirement. So should class contain even a bit of logic, I'm putting it into the corresponding assembly, even if this logic is inaccessible by end user.

Comment: That's what I am saying: IMHO, there will be no interface for a DTO. And no interface means the question is solved: It belongs into `Common.Interfaces` because it is an accompanying  class of the interface it is used in.